# Html dynamic table via div

Tags: html, html-table

How create table via div which always centered  their cells. I mean, if width for example 302 px, table show 3 divs in one line with width of 90px, and space between those divs and border are equal (8px). And if table width changed to 210px, 2 div will shown in one line with equal  space (10px), and third div will move to the next line. Window width is dynamic.

Comment: Please clarify your math, I don't see how 3*90+ 3*8 = 302 it is 294 right?

Comment: I belive my answer is still solid, I would suggest you drop the table all togheter and focus on css + html divs, the html tables are a barren path...

Comment: Sorry,302 is right.
If 3(div)*90 + 4(space)*8=302

Comment: Ok if you say so, but I figure like this div a, div b, div c =
90+8+90+8+90 = 270 + 16 = 286 which means both of us where wrong...

Comment: 8+90+8+90+8+90+8 it's what I mean.
But if you know solution for your example it will be helpful.

Comment: You can use css for this if you use bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using css and frameworks such as: [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [zurb foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)n, [Check this out to get the overlaying image about responsive frameworks](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) these have pre-set setups but you can also modify them to your liking..

You would need to change

```
x,y,z
```

to suit you because I don't exactly follow your math, [HTML tables are out dated and should not be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html?rq=1)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-x">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-y">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-z">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>
```